# Prove: $\|v\|\le\|T(v)\|\le9\|v\|$, Given a linear transformation $T$ defined as $T(x,y)=(x+2y, 2x+y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, quadratic-forms

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as $T\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\
2 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)$.

**Prove** that $\|v\|\le\|T(v)\|\le9\|v\|$, for every $v\ = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. as $\|v\|$ is the norm of the vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the standard inner product.

***My Attempt:***

as the transformation matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\
2 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ is symmetric, we conclude that $T$ is Hermitian ($T=T^{*}$), which also means that $T$ is a normal transformation. I've tried to use quadratic forms as I can't understand exactly in what way one should handle the norm of a matrix.

the quadratic form I found for $T$ is:

$q(x_1,x_2)= x_1^2 +4x_1 x_2 + x_2^2$.

suppose $y_1 = x_1 + 2x_2, y_2 = x_2$ and $q(y) = y_{1}^2 -3y^2_2  $, hence by the change of bases we conclude that $q(x)$ and the transformation $T$ can be represented by the diagonal matrix:

$$A =    \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -3
\end{array}\right).$$

How - or **can we** continue from here?

Comment: **Hint:** $\|Av\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2 \|v\|_2$ where $\|A\|_2= \sigma_{max} = 3$